# Are the elements of an array within the range of another array

Tags: ruby

For these arrays:

```
array_a = [50,13,25, 35, 45]
array_b = [14,45]
```

I want to know if every value in b is with the range of values in a.

Here the result should be `true` because both 14 and 45 are between 13 and 50.

Comment: Cool. Let us know when you're done.

Comment: Its done by @adrian answer

Comment: We expect YOU to show effort by providing code YOU wrote to solve the problem, with an explanation of why it doesn't work for you. Asking for code without showing effort is considered very bad form on Stack Overflow and is a great way to get your question closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array_a = [50,13,25,35,45]
array_b = [14,45]
array_a.max >= array_b.max && array_a.min <= array_b.min
# => true
```

Edit: Babai's solution is slightly faster and more elegant, I think.

Edit: So most efficient solution is:

```
array_a = [50,13,25,35,45]
array_b = [14,45]
min,max = array_a.minmax
array_b.all? {|num| num<=max && num>=min }
# => true
```

Comment: what OP wanted to see,can you tell? I am still confused.

Comment: _Babai's solution is slightly faster and more elegant_.  Try this: `puts 15.between?(20, 1)` or `puts 15.between?(20, 1, 4)`  If we know the second array has size 2 and it's sorted, then there's no need for min/max, you can more efficiently write b[0] and b[1] (or b.first and b.last).  Also, if you think about how between? works, comparing directly is going to be faster than calling a method to do the comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [50,13,25, 35, 45]
b = [13,45]

mina, maxa = a.minmax
result = b.all? {|num| mina <= num and num <= maxa }
puts result

--output:--
true
```

Or incorporating Adrian's idea:

```
a = [50, 13, 25, 35, 45]
b = [13, 45]

mina, maxa = a.minmax
minb, maxb = b.minmax

result = (mina <= minb and maxb <= maxa)
puts result

--output:--
true
```

Comment: Obtaining the min() and max() of both arrays requires traversing each array twice.  minmax() traverses the first array once, and all? traverses the second array once.  More efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I would do as below :-

```
a = [50,13,25, 35, 45]
b = [13,45]
min_max_a = a.minmax
b.all? {|num| num.between?(*min_max_a) }
# => true
```

Comment: I originally wrote `(mina..maxa).include?(num)`

Comment: @7stud You are right!!